# how to merge month and year columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a sample table 'calender' in mysql

```
id    month     year    
 1      9       2020
 2      1       2020
 3     10       2020
```

Desired result

```
id    month   year    monthyear
 1      9     2020     202009
 2      1     2020     202001
 3     10     2020     202010
```

I've tried `CONCAT()` function, but it won't work for the single digit month number. Looking for help.

Comment: Simply use LPAD().

Answer (score 2):

If your data are int, just do :

```
(year * 100) + month
```

if your data are string, cast them as int first.

```
cast(cast(year as int) * 100 + cast(month as int) as varchar)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *, concat(year, LPAD(month,2,'0')) as monthyear from calender;
```